# Grafana Singlestat panel color threshold for 0 and 1 value

Tags: grafana

I have a singlestat panel on my Grafana dashboard that shows wether a system is UP or DOWN. Its source is `0` and `1` and I simply used the value mappings for that.

Now I want "UP" to appear in green and "DOWN" to appear in red but I have problems defining the threshold.

I tried `0:1`, `0.1:0.9`, and `0,1:0,9` but none of that works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it out: It's `0.1,1` with inverted colors.